# Expenses tracker

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a page, where people could track there expenses.

After successful registration, you land on administration page, where you can insert specific expense:

```
<?php

session_start();

session_regenerate_id();

include("db_connection.php");

if(!(isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string']) || isset($_COOKIE['username']))){

    header("Location: index.html");
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['rsubmit'])){

    $electricity = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['electricity']);
    $gas = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['gas']);
}

$insert = "INSERT INTO `vrednosti`(vrednost, cas) VALUES ('$electricity', '$gas', now())";

if (mysqli_query($link, $insert)) {
    echo "Changes saved!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insert . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link); ?>


<br><br><br><br>

<form action="" method="post">
    Electricity:<br> <input type="text" name="electricity" id="electricity"></input><br>
    Gas:<br> <input type="text" name="gas" id="gas"></input><br>
    <input type="submit" name="rsubmit" id="rsubmit" value="Insert"></input><br>
</form>
```

The problem is, that inserted values doesn`t get into my mysql database, where I have 3 tables:

1) Users:

```
1 id / int(11) / AUTO_INCREMENT 
2 Username / varchar(32)    
3 Email / varchar(80)   
4 Password / char(128)  
5 Activation / varchar(40)                  NULL
6 ExpirationTime / timestamp                NULL        
7 Salt / char(128)  
8 gender / varchar(6)   
9 birthdate / text  
10 education / varchar(30)
```

2) Categories (currently only 2 categories):

```
 1 cat_id / int(11) / AUTO_INCREMENT
 2 Electricity / varchar(60)    
 3 Gas / varchar(60)
```

3) Values:

```
1 value_id / int(30) / AUTO_INCREMENT   
2 values / varchar(60)  
3 time / timestamp
```

Can Anyone here help me with this page. I tried everything, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: you need to run 3 queries to insert data into 3 different tables

Comment: You need to write your third column name in your insert query `INSERT INTO `vrednosti`(vrednost, cas,THIRED_COLUMN) VALUES ('$electricity', '$gas', now())";`

Comment: What is "THIRED_COLUMN" ? INSERT INTO values(value, time,THIRED_COLUMN) VALUES ('$electricity', '$gas', now())";

Comment: he doesn't has the 3rd col in that table, he needs to run more then one query

Answer (score 0):

In order to add 2 new entries to the "Values" table you should have two queries for that:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `vrednosti`(values, time) VALUES ('$electricity', now())";

and 

$insert2 = "INSERT INTO `vrednosti`(values, time) VALUES ('$gas', now())";
```

Comment: Ok. That`seems to be more logical. Aditional question: what should I do, to get user ID into value ("vrednosti") table? (From session cookie)

Comment: First of all it seems you need to add a new column in the "Values" table for User ID.
Then you should run a query like
$insert = "INSERT INTO `vrednosti`(user_id,values, time) VALUES ('$_SESSION[your_variable_name_for_userid]', '$electricity', now())";

Comment: I don`t know why, but this isnt working. It gives me an error: Error: INSERT INTO `vrednosti`(vrednost, cas,) VALUES ('', now())
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ('', now())' at line 1

Comment: + still don`know if [your_variable_name_for_userid] is $id or $username ?

Comment: + if i would like to know which form was submited, I must add new collumn "categories" into values. How to connect that together?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly get result!

```
<?php

session_start();

session_regenerate_id();

include("db_connection.php");

if(!(isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string']) || isset($_COOKIE['username']))){

    header("Location: index.html");
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['rsubmit'])){

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];      

    $kategorija = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['kategorija']);

    $vrednost = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['kolicina']);

    // query

    $insert = "INSERT INTO `vrednosti`(vrednost, cas, username, kategorija) VALUES ('".$vrednost."', now(), '".$username."', '".$kategorija."')";

    var_dump($insert);



    if (mysqli_query($link, $insert)) {
        echo "Vrednost shranjena!";
    } else {
        echo "Napaka: " . $vstavi . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
    }

}


mysqli_close($link);
```

?>